# Metro style & winJS: is there a way to know if an element is outside the screen?

Tags: listview, microsoft-metro, winjs

In a horizontal listView - is it possible to know whether a certain fragment is "outside" the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because WinJS is essentially running in IE 10, you can approach this as you would a regular web issue. Some of this is borrowed from  [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/487073/428823)

Using JQuery, you can do:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)
      && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) &&  (elemTop >= docViewTop) );
}
```

You can also do it in pure "WinJS" (Internet Explorer 10 + JavaScript), it would look something like:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = window.pageXOffset;
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + window.innerHeight;

    var elemTop = =  document.getElementById(elem).offsetTop
    var elemBottom = elemTop + =  document.getElementById(elem).offsetHeight

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)
      && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) &&  (elemTop >= docViewTop) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I've changed it to fit a horizontal view rather than a vertical one:

function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
      var docViewLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
    var docViewRight = docViewLeft + $(window).width();

    var elemLeft = $(elem).offset().left;
    var elemRight = elemLeft + $(elem).width();

    return ((elemRight >= docViewLeft) && (elemLeft <= docViewRight)
      && (elemRight <= docViewRight) && (elemLeft >= docViewLeft));
}

Cheers!

Comment: @Mike86 Thanks for the code update! Glad to see things working for you!